# Single word for "better but harder" or "greater but harder to achieve"?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

For example, "The new English test is **better but harder to achieve**."
I need to change the phrase (marked in bold) in the sentence above to a single word. what word will fit?
Any help is appreciated.

Edit: To clarify for those asking, I need to shorten this phrase as I have a word limit on a paper I'm writing.

Comment: I’m not sure there is a single word. Why can’t you use multiple words?

Comment: Why do you "need to change" that long phrase into just one word?

Comment: A test can't be _achieved_, though a mark/grade on a test can be.

Comment: If want just one word, the term is "single word". "Singular" means not plural, or unique.

Answer (score 1):

There's no word that clearly communicates both of those means, but "rigorous" comes close.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If there is no other word that fits, "rigorous" should work well.

also, thanks for the word correction. I've fixed it now.

Comment: Note that you would have to say ***more** rigorous* to get the comparative sense of your original phrase.